# Stored Procedure - delete from table with joins

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2017

I'm trying to learn SQL and I've run into a problem with stored procedures. I've got a tables structure like in the picture, where `Repair.RepairerId` and `Repair.CarId` are foreign keys for the appropriate tables.

[image: DB structure]

What I need to do is to create a stored procedure that allows a user to delete entities from table Repair where user can select the car model and the repairer name in Microsoft SQL Server 2017.

For now I have the next code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[DeleteRepairInfo]
    @Name nvarchar(MAX),
    @Model nvarchar(MAX)
AS
    DELETE Repair.*
    FROM Repair INNER JOIN Repairer ON Repair.RepairerId = Repairer.Id
                INNER JOIN Car ON Repair.CarId = Car.Id
    WHERE Car.Model LIKE @Model AND Repairer.Name LIKE @Name
GO
```

However SQL Editor in Visual Studio 2017 gives me the error:

> SQL46010: Incorrect syntax near ..

Also all the `INNER JOIN` statements and their `=` signs are greyed out as well as words `LIKE`, `AND`, and the final `LIKE`. (I'm not sure if this is okay).

You can see this on the next picture:

[image]

Comment: What's the rest of `SQL46010: Incorrect syntax near ..` say?

Comment: BTW, the SQL Keywords being "greyed out" is actually just SSMS syntax highlighting.

Comment: Remove the artistic. Just `DELETE Repair FROM ...`

Comment: @digital.aaron it says nothing else, just the exact thing I've mentioned. And thank you for your answer about SSMS syntax!

Comment: Ah, ok, now it makes sense. The error is telling you that the incorrect syntax is at the period in `DELETE Repair.*`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would write the logic as:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[DeleteRepairInfo] (
    @Name nvarchar(MAX),
    @Model nvarchar(MAX)
) AS
BEGIN
    DELETE r
    FROM Repair r INNER JOIN
         Repairer rr
         ON r.RepairerId = rr.Id INNER JOIN
         Car c
         ON r.CarId = c.Id
    WHERE c.Model LIKE @Model AND rr.Name LIKE @Name;
END;  -- DeleteRepairInfo
```

The issues with your query is the syntax `Repair.*`.  That is not valid.  Note some other things:

- This introduces table aliases so the query is easier to write and to read.
- The body of the stored procedure is surrounded by `BEGIN`/`END` so it is easy to see.
- The `END` is commented with the name of the stored procedure.
- The arguments are surrounded by parentheses.

These are all "optional".  But writing clear code is a good habit to learn.

Comment: It should also be mentioned that using `LIKE` the way the @Vovch wrote it proooooobably won't work the way the s/he intended, unless wildcard characters are added to the parameters before passing them to the stored proc. It may be more useful to use `Model LIKE '%' + @Model + '%'`

Comment: @digital.aaron Yes, you are totally right! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

How are you?

I think the problem is that you're not using the `DELETE` properly

The follow example will help you!

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[DeleteRepairInfo]
    @Name nvarchar(MAX),
    @Model nvarchar(MAX)
AS
    DELETE FROM Repair as R
    WHERE R.CarId in (select CarId from Car where Model = @Model) 
    and R.RepairerId in (select RepairerId from Repairer where Name = @Name)        
GO
```

Assuming that you can have more than 1 car with the same model and more than one repairer with the same name!

Good luck :)

Comment: Thanks, you're totally right. It's sad that I can give only one "Right answer" badge. :)